# How to start a COM server implemented in python?

Tags: python, windows, com

I am using python for making a COM local server. In fact, the whole COM part is implemented in a dll and my python script is calling that dll thanks to ctypes. It works ok when I run the script manually.

I would like to see my server automatically ran when a COM client request it. I know that it is possible by giving the command line as value of the LocalServer32 registry key.

Unfortunatelly, I can't manage to see windows running my python script properly. I've tried to use python and pythonw with a similar problems. It seems that windows is adding a "-Embedding" flag to the command line and I guess that it can be a problem for python.

Any ideas?

Does anybody how to avoid the "-Embedding" flag in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "-embedding" flag is [added by COM automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908849.aspx), the purpose of which is so that the server application can parse this flag to determine that it was run by COM.

> COM appends the "-Embedding" flag to
>   the string, so the application that
>   uses flags will need to parse the
>   whole string and check for the
>   -Embedding flag. The following code example shows the setting for this
>   value.

You will need to handle this in your server code.

Comment: The "-Embedding" flag was badly handled by my script. It works ok now. Thanks for your help